# Dictionary has no suitable copy constructor

Tags: .net, json, serialization, dictionary, c++-cli

I am trying to convert a string in JSON format to a Dictionary, see below:

```
using namespace System::Web::Script::Serialization;

...

String ^data = "{Name: 'sherlock', Problem: 'deserialization'}";
JavaScriptSerializer ^serializer = gcnew JavaScriptSerializer();
Dictionary<String^, Object^> obj = serializer->Deserialize<Dictionary<String^, Object^>>(data);
```

I'm getting an error,

```
class "System::Collections::Generic::Dictionary<System::String ^, System::Object ^>" has no suitable copy constructor
```

I'm new to c++/cli coming from c#. I think I understand what a copy constructor is but I'm not sure why one would be needed in this case, or how to resolve this error ..

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You forgot the `^` for the Dictionary reference itself.

Change:

```
Dictionary<String^, Object^> obj = 
          serializer->Deserialize<Dictionary<String^, Object^>>(data);
```

to:

```
Dictionary<String^, Object^>^ obj = 
          serializer->Deserialize<Dictionary<String^, Object^>^>(data);
```

Note the 3rd `^` just before `obj` as well as before `(data)`.

Comment: Thanks, I'm still getting the hang of these handles. I think another one is needed for the generic T arg dictionary also, this fixed the problem. Thanks again!